# relocation R_X86_64_32 against a local symbol' error

Tags: svn, openssl

I am trying to install Subversion with Apache support. I installed `apr`, `apr-utils`, `neon`, and `OpenSSL` with the `--enable-shared` flag. However, I get the following error when trying to install subversion:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr0/software/openssl/ossl/lib/libssl.a(s23_clnt.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `a local symbol' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr0/software/openssl/ossl/lib/libssl.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [libserf-0.la] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr0/sources/svn/subversion-1.6.3/serf'
make: *** [external-all] Error 1
```

On the Subversion FAQ it is stated that if I get this error, I should use the `--enable-shared` flag and it should work. However, that doesn't help. Any ideas on how to get around this?

Comment: Might be a good idea to ask this also in serverfault.com (and add a link between them)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out that the problem was with the openssl install. Reinstalling openssl with enable-shared worked.

Comment: just ran into this, too
/usr/bin/ld: /root/installs/lib/libssl.a(s23_clnt.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `a local symbol' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/root/installs/lib/libssl.a: could not read symbols: Bad value

$ ./config shared
this fixed it thanks!

Comment: I also have the same problem, what do you mean by saing "Reinstalling openssl with enable-shared worked"? can you plaese explain? thanks!

Comment: @RRR, when configuring openssl ,run:
 `./config shared `

Answer (score 1):

I solve it with adding hidden attribute to OPENSSL_ia32cap_P in crypto\cryptolib.h and recompile.

```
extern unsigned int OPENSSL_ia32cap_P[] __attribute__ ((visibility ("hidden")));
```

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this in a couple of other non-openssl scenarios, and I've found that this is generally related to not having shared libraries turned on.

Adding `--enable-shared` to your configure line seems to fix it.