# OpenSSL installation error (could not read symbols: Bad value)

Tags: c, linux, openssl, fedora

I am trying to install openssl1.0.1e on a 64bit FC16 machine. I already have one older version (1.0.0j) installed in my machine. My application is having some memory corruption and trying to debug it through valgrind tool. Valgrind shows lots of "Uninitialized Variable" message for openssl functions which I want to suppress by installing latest openSSL with PURIFY macro enabled. I am installing it using following commands

```
./config -DPURIFY shared

make
```

`make` is stopping installation and throwing below errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: libcrypto.a(e_4758cca.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.data' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
libcrypto.a(e_4758cca.o): could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[4]: *** [link_a.gnu] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/downloads/openssl-1.0.1e'
make[3]: *** [do_linux-shared] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/downloads/openssl-1.0.1e'
make[2]: *** [libcrypto.so.1.0.0] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/downloads/openssl-1.0.1e'
make[1]: *** [shared] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/downloads/openssl-1.0.1e/crypto'
make: *** [build_crypto] Error 1
```

What could be the reason for this error?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [relocation R\_X86\_64\_32 against a local symbol' error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147890/relocation-r-x86-64-32-against-a-local-symbol-error)

Comment: I already looked into that post before posting here, but didn't find an answer there. I am trying to install openSSL alone.

One correction, I had tried ./config -DPURIFY shared && make. Since I need the shared object outputs. Will edit in the question.

Comment: Have have the same issue. Manage to figure this one out?