# How to resolve this libtool linking error

Tags: c, gcc, shared-libraries, libtool, fpic

Command used to link:

```
**libtool --tag=CC --mode=link gcc -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/home/ovsdpdk/rpmbuild/BUILD/openvswitch-2.4.0.1/openvswitch-2.4.0/include/ -I/home/ovsdpdk/rpmbuild/BUILD/openvswitch-2.4.0.1/openvswitch-2.4.0/lib/ -O3  -lxml2 -lnetconf -lopenvswitch -lovsdb -lpthread -lcrypto -lssl -lrt -laio -avoid-version -module -shared -export-dynamic --mode=link -o ietf-interfaces.la .obj/ietf-interfaces.lo .obj/ovs_mediation.lo -rpath /usr/local/lib**
```

Error:

```
libtool: link: gcc -shared  -fPIC -DPIC  .obj/.libs/ietf-interfaces.o .obj/.libs/ovs_mediation.o   -lxml2 -lnetconf -lopenvswitch -lovsdb -lpthread -lcrypto -lssl -lrt -laio  -O3   -Wl,-soname -Wl,ietf-interfaces.so -o .libs/ietf-interfaces.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopenvswitch.a(ovsdb-idl.o): relocation R_X86_64_TPOFF32 against `var.7533' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/libopenvswitch.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: The answer is right there in the error message. Recompile with -fPIC.

Comment: Got the same error, even if i compile with -fPIC

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147890/relocation-r-x86-64-32-against-a-local-symbol-error?rq=1

Comment: You have a static libopenswitch.a, have you build *it* with -fPIC?

Comment: Thanks n.m. I have compiled openvswitch as u suggested, `export CFLAGS=-fPIC`,`./configure --enable-shared` . Its working now.